# How would I add a second line to a <div> and make it have a different font size?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm currently working on a simple COVID-19 site where some info gathered from some flask code is shown in s, with some CSS making the backgrounds into white boxes. However, I am not completely sure how I can add a "cases" right underneath the number while still being in the box. I'm sorry if my question is slightly unclear. I will show my code below.

HTML I am attempting to use:

```
<div class="boxed">{{data}}</div>
<div><p>cases</p></div>
```

CSS I am attempting to use:

```
.boxed {
  font-size: 800%;
  width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 80px;

  background: whitesmoke;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;

  color: rgb(49,74,128);

  margin: 2% auto;

  border-radius: 60px;
}
```

Right now, the "cases" text shows under the box with the number in it, instead of being inside of it.

I apologize if it is kind of a bad or simple question- I am a beginner in making websites. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not Move the `<p>` tag inside the `div.boxed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `p` tag inside `div.boxed` and add separate CSS for title and cases

```css
.boxed {
  font-size: 800%;
  width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 80px;

  background: whitesmoke;

  color: rgb(49,74,128);

  margin: 2% auto;

  border-radius: 60px;
}

.title {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.body {
   /* your body styling */
}
```

```html
<div class="boxed">
  <div class="title">{{data}}</div>
  <p class="body">cases</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move `<p>cases</p>` inside your .boxed div.

```
<div class="boxed">
{{data}}
<p>cases</p>
</div>
```

Then add the styling below to your css.

```
.boxed p {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

Testing: https://jsfiddle.net/z3acqfjg/1/